# How does change in temperature affect experimental calculation of molar mass

Tags: gas-laws

This is coming from AP Chemistry 2009 q2 f. To sum it up, a student undercalculates the molar mass of a gas that is flushed into a sealed flask of dry air using DRT/P, and you have to justify if the following occurrence is responsible for the error. "The temperature of the air was 23.0°C, but the temperature of the CO2(g) was lower than the reported 23.0°C." The explanation provided says that it would not have been responsible because the result would be greater density and then larger mass therefore higher calculated molar mass. My question is if the temperature increases the volume and therefore the density, would it not also increase the pressure, balancing the increase in density out, and create the same calculated molar mass?

Comment: If you know the temperature, it works at any temperature. If you plug in the correct density but the wrong temperature, the resulting molar mass will be off.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if the temperature increases the volume and therefore the density

Let's stop here for a second. Volume is **inversely proportional** to density according to the equation:
$$D = \frac{m}{V}$$

Therefore, if the temperature increases the volume as you had said, the density would actually decrease. You are right about how increasing the temperature will also increase the pressure. Now, looking at the equation:
$$M=\frac{DRT}{P}$$
You can see that a decrease in density and increase in pressure would actually decrease the molar mass. I hope this would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware how you get the gas into a sealed container. It seems that a weighed vessel of air of known volume at a specified measured T was flushed with a gas and resealed at atmospheric pressure: constant P constant V but the gas was colder so that means there were more molecules in the volume more mass and a higher MW.  If the results were too low the more reasonable source of error would be impure gas mix in the sample, air or water.